Select records close to each other, with between two date of birth SQL
I am trying to run a query based on what is stated in the title, select records close to each other, with between two dates of birth, without success
so far I have tried this looking from left to right, what I want is to return only the users who are between the dates that the current user will have sent in post, and between the distance
id | lat        | long       | age_birth
1   47.55314000  -1.53200000  2011-07-05
2   47.55314000  -1.53200000  2008-07-05
3   47.55314000  -1.53200000  2008-07-05
4 ....

The current user wants to display other users in the same area say within 25 km around, which is between 20 and 35 years old.
Using latitude and longitude.
I hope this is clear, 'I am French ^^'
if (!function_exists('Dot_Distance')) {
    function Dot_Distance($lat_u, $long_u, $or, $sex, $age, $age_tow, $age_olders, $uid, $distance){
      global $db;
      $latitude = $lat_u;
      $longitude = $long_u;
      $distance = $distance;
      $sagea = 'AND ('.$age_olders.' BETWEEN (YEAR(CURDATE())- ' . $age . ')  AND (YEAR(CURDATE())-' . $age_tow . '))';

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT *,  (((acos(sin(( $latitude * pi() / 180)) *sin(( `lat_` * pi() / 180)) +
      cos(( $latitude * pi() /180 ))*cos(( `lat_` * pi() / 180)) * cos((( $longitude - `long_`) *
      pi()/180)))) * 180/pi()) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344) as distance
      FROM `users`
      WHERE
      lat_ IS NOT NULL AND
      long_ IS NOT NULL
      AND
      orientation = '$or'
      AND sex = '$sex'
      $sagea // return 2008-07-05 / 2011-07-05
      AND id <> '$uid'
      HAVING distance < '$distance'
      ORDER BY distance * 1 ASC");

      $query->execute();

      $query = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

      // var_dump($sagea);
      return $query;


}
}
// a not

Thanks in advance

I would advise to remove PHP code from this question as it makes it less clear.

There's some really dangerous SQL injection going on there.

Yes for SQL injection, after I execute this correctly just for less code here, this all ->execute(['' => $

Please update your question with enough sample data to illustrate the possible use cases and the the result you want to achieve, based on that data - all as editable text formatted as tables
